# How to get right Offset on detectTapGestures after Pinch Zoom - Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm attempting to retrieve the offset of a tap-point on an image using detectTapGestures. However, I'm encountering a discrepancy in the offset values between when the image is zoomed in and when it's not.

```
        var scale by remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }
        var offset by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset(0f, 0f)) }
        var myPan by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset(0f, 0f)) }

        val modifier = Modifier
            .clip(RectangleShape)
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectTapGestures { myOffset ->

                    val x = myOffset.x
                    val y = myOffset.y

                    Timber.e("myOffset X $x")
                    Timber.e("myOffset Y $y")

                    onClick(Offset(x, y))
                }
            }
            .pointerInput(Unit) {

                detectTransformGestures { _, pan, zoom, _ ->
                    scale = (scale * zoom).coerceIn(1f, 5f)
                    myPan = pan
                    val extraWidth = (scale - 1) * customPainter.painterSize.width
                    val extraHeight = (scale - 1) *  customPainter.painterSize.height

                    val maxX = extraWidth / 2
                    val maxY = extraHeight / 2

                    offset = Offset(
                        x = (offset.x + pan.x).coerceIn(-maxX, maxX),
                        y = (offset.y + pan.y).coerceIn(-maxY, maxY),
                    )

                }
            }

        Box(
            modifier = modifier
        ) {

            Image(

                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                    .graphicsLayer(
                    scaleX = scale, scaleY = scale,
                    translationX = offset.x, translationY = offset.y,
                ),
                contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth,
                painter = customPainter
            )
```

EDIT: if the image is only dragged and **not** zoomed in, the right offset is calculated as:

```
           detectTapGestures { myOffset ->

            val x = myOffset.x - offset.x
            val y = myOffset.y - offset.y

            Timber.e("myOffset X $x")
            Timber.e("myOffset Y $y")

            onClick(Offset(x, y))
        }
```

when zoomed in i have tried:

```
            val x = myOffset.x - offset.x / scale
            val y = myOffset.y - offset.y /scale
```

with no succes.

How can I accurately determine the offset for a clicked point when the image is zoomed in?